# Image handler images not showing in Chrome and FF

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am displaying employee profile image from **database** using Handler . Images are displaying fine in Internet Explorer but they are not displaying in Chrome and Firefox . 
What could be the problem ?

Here is my code :

**aspx :**

```
<%  img_profile.ImageUrl="~/Handler.ashx?empcd="+Session["empcd"].ToString() ;
  %>
<asp:Image CssClass="img-rounded img-responsive profile" runat="server" ID="img_profile" Width="150" Height="150"  />
```

**Image Handler Code :**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        OracleDataReader rdr = null;
        OracleConnection dbConn;
        dbConn = Conn.getConn();
        string empcd = context.Request.QueryString["empcd"].ToString();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select photo img from olphrm.emp_personal where emp_code='"+empcd+"'", dbConn);

        dbConn.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {

        context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])rdr["img"]);
        }
        if (rdr != null)
         rdr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

This is the output on Chrome :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Thanks in Advance for your help !!!

**UPDATE :**

I've added the following code in my aspx page ,now the image person.png is displayed ,it means that there is any error .How can I find and resolve this error ?

```
    <% img_profile.ImageUrl="~/Handler.ashx?empcd="+Session["empcd"].ToString() ;

  img_profile.Attributes["onerror"] = "this.src='Images/person.png';";
                                                         %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying a `ContentType`. And adding `content-Length` is good practice.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    //create a new byte array
    byte[] bin = new byte[0];

    //get your data from the db
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        bin = (byte[])rdr["img"];
    }

    //clear the buffer stream
    context.Response.ClearHeaders();
    context.Response.Clear();
    context.Response.Buffer = true;

    //set the correct ContentType
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

    //set the filename for the pdf
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myImage.jpg\"");

    //set the correct length of the string being send
    context.Response.AddHeader("content-Length", bin.Length.ToString());

    //send the byte array to the browser
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);

    //cleanup
    context.Response.Flush();
    context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

> Your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection since you do not
>   validate `empcd` and you aren't using parameterized queries.

Comment: Then the image is probably not stored correctly. You can test this by changing the image from the DB with an image from disk and send that.

Comment: if there is a problem in image , why its displaying in IE ?

Comment: Could be because IE doesn't adhere to some standards as well as other browsers. And sending the images as Base64 didn't work either.

Comment: You need to fix the original problem, not adding a fix to display an standard image. Try sending an image from disk as i've mentioned before.

Comment: actually I'm working in a company , due to some restrictions i can not update the image in the table :(

Answer (score -1):

You should convert it to base64 string.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        OracleDataReader rdr = null;
        OracleConnection dbConn;
        dbConn = Conn.getConn();
        string empcd = context.Request.QueryString["empcd"].ToString();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select photo img from olphrm.emp_personal where emp_code='"+empcd+"'", dbConn);

        dbConn.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {

        context.Response.Write( Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])rdr["img"]) );
        }
        if (rdr != null)
         rdr.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: How and where should I call this method ?

Comment: just modified the answer.  
changed at :

context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])rdr["img"]);

Comment: you have a lot of record for each? or single record?

Comment: I have did some changes again in the answer.  maybe you check again is it the latest one.

Comment: Obviously a single record per employee , records doesn't matter here because it's working fine in Internet Explorer

Comment: what is your error? your sql statement seems problem.

Comment: There's no any error , image is not displaying , because if there's any error , why it's working on internet explorer

Comment: you should be using ajax call this ashx right? if you using chrome. press F12 and see console if there are any error ?

Comment: maybe your text should return @"data:image/gif;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])rdr["img"])

Comment: I've already tried it when you posted the answer but it's not working :(

Comment: Please show me the output HTML code what is the Image URL?

Comment: can you enter handler.ashx?empcd=619 in your webpage to see what is the output?

Comment: Why convert to base64?